# Linking a button to a list element in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a array of `answer` objects and I am using a for loop in ejs to display them to the user. An answer object has an `id`, a `text` and a boolean `correct` attribute.

```
<% answers.forEach((answer)=>{ %>
  <li>
    <p><%=answer.text%></p>
    <button>CORRECT</button>
  </li>
<%})%>
```

I want a user to be able to click on the correct answer and have my script send the `id` of the answer that was clicked to the server so I can update the `correct` attribute for that specific answer in my Mongo database. Possibly something like:

```
$(the_button_clicked).click((event)=>{
  $.ajax({
    sending the correct answer to the database
  });
});
```

The problem is that this is a list and I don't know how to link each specific answer to its correct button. I can probably add a class or id to the button element and set it to `answer.id` but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing it. I feel like this should be a common pattern.

Comment: `<button onclick="sendAnswer('<%=answer.id%>')">CORRECT</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data-attribute to store custom data in your HTML. Probably good idea to give your button a class also.

```
<% answers.forEach((answer)=>{ %>
  <li>
    <p><%=answer.text%></p>
    <button class="correct" data-id="<%=answer.id%>">CORRECT</button>
  </li>
<%})%>
```

In your jQuery, create an onclick handler to your button and get its related id by using [this.dataset.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access) or [$(this).data('id')](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5);

```
$('button.correct').click(function () {
    var id = this.dataset.id;
    // do something with id 
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('button.correct').click(function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log("this.dataset.id", this.dataset.id);
    console.log("$(this).data('id')", $(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>A</p>
    <button class="correct" data-id="1">CORRECT</button></li>
  <li>
    <p>B</p>
    <button class="correct" data-id="2">CORRECT</button></li>
  <li>
    <p>C</p>
    <button class="correct" data-id="3">CORRECT</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have tried both the jQuery way and the vanilla js and it is `undefined` for jQuery and it gives an error for vanilla js. When i console.log $(this) it is the window object and not the button.

Comment: @user3117051 Inspect your HTML and ensure that the HTML is correct. Ensure that you adding your event handler to the correct elements also. If you use `data-someName` in your HTML, then it should be `this.dataset.someName` or `$(this).data('someName')`. See the demo in my edit.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The problem was that I was using ()=>{...} as opposed to function(){...}. Have you any idea as to why this was the case?

Comment: @user3117051 Ah, I often make that mistake too. [Arrow functions does not have its own `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it doing like this !

```
<% for(var i=0;i<myObj.length;i++) { %>

<span onclick="getId('<%=myObj[i].id%>')"><%=myObj[i].name%></span>

<% } %>
```